# Why do matrices not work with other degree equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was recently trying to solve a set of equations where the degree of the equation was $2$, you can see my work [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3709466/how-to-find-a-b-and-c/).
But after solving it I got an answer which did not satisfy the original equations. So this is the reason why I wanted to ask, **Why do matrices and doing elimination not work when dealing with equations other than linear ones?**, and if there is a way to make it work, please tell me.

Similar are the following set of equations:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{c}
a+b-c=1\\
a^2+b^2-c^2=-1\\
a^3+b^3-c^3=1\end{array}\right.$$
This set has the solution
$$a=0, 
b=0, 
c=-1$$

If we reframe this in the form of matrices, we get this:
$$\left[\begin{matrix}
1&1&-1\\
a&b&-c\\
a^2&b^2&-c^2
\end{matrix}\right]
%
\left[\begin{matrix}
a\\
b\\
c
\end{matrix}\right]
%
=\left[\begin{matrix}
1\\
-1\\
1
\end{matrix}\right]$$
But after performing elimination and bringing it into the reduced row echelon form, we get this:
$$\left[\begin{matrix}
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1
\end{matrix}\right]
%
\left[\begin{matrix}
a\\
b\\
c
\end{matrix}\right]
%
=\left[\begin{matrix}
\frac{bc+b+c+1}{a^2-ab-ac+bc}\\
\frac{ac+a+c+1}{-ab+ac+b^2-bc}\\
\frac{ab+a+b+1}{-ab+ac+bc-c^2}
\end{matrix}\right]$$
But this set has no solutions! Why is it so?

Comment: [Gröbner basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gröbner_basis)

Comment: You could as well ask why $x^2+y^2\neq (x+y)^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elimination *does* work with polynomial equations. For your equations $a+b-c=1$ and $a^2+b^2-c^2=1$ we may eliminate $c$
by setting $c=a+b-1$ and then solve the quadratic equation in
$a$ and $b$ - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3709466/how-to-find-a-b-and-c/). In the general case, for polynomial equations, the "elimination theory" becomes of course  much more complicated than in the linear case. It includes Groebner bases, for example.

However, matrix equations are different (your title), because matrices do not commute in general.
Here we have to be very careful. 
For example, the quadratic matrix equation 
$$
X^2=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \cr 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
in $M_2(\Bbb C)$ has no solution.